# What is happening during this operation 0x99<<j & (0x80>>i))

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, motordriver

i've been tinkering around, and i have googled and searched about bitwise operations.
and i think i understand some of it, however i have a piece of code i have copied from someone online which allows it to move a 28byj-48 5v motor and driver in python. its actually the only code i've found in python that it would allow it to work.

however, i tried breaking it down with my own code and cant seem to figure out why mine wont work but this one does.

here it is, the working one:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

#configuring pins and motors
motorPin = (18,23,24,25)     #GPIO pin in BCM mode refer to map
rolePerMinute =13
stepsPerRevolution = 2048
stepSpeed = (60/rolePerMinute)/stepsPerRevolution


#setup the pins to the motor
def setup():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    for i in motorPin:
        GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)



def rotary1():
    n =1
    while n < 10000:
        for j in range(4):
            for i in range(4):
                GPIO.output(motorPin[i],0x99>>j & (0x08>>i))
            sleep(stepSpeed)
            n +=1
```

and here is mine:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

#configuring pins and motors
motorPin = (18,23,24,25)     #GPIO pin in BCM mode refer to map
rolePerMinute =13
stepsPerRevolution = 2048
stepSpeed = (60/rolePerMinute)/stepsPerRevolution


#setup the pins to the motor
def setup():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    for i in motorPin:
        GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT)

def rotary():
    n = 1
    while n < 10000:

        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>1 & (0x08>>1))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(23,0x99>>2 & (0x08>>2))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(24,0x99>>3 & (0x08>>3))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(25,0x99>>4 & (0x08>>4))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        n+= 1
```

if im understanding this correctly,  0X99 is transformed into a bit "10011001" and its ">>" bit wise operator is pushing it by 1 to the left?

this is where im confused, and also why wouldn't my stepped version work versus the first version.

if someone could help me understand this, i would be greatful.

many thanks.

i've tried googling how bitwise work and watched a very informative video, however i still couldnt understand how << or >> works in this case with Hex values.
I also couldn't get my stepped version to work, versus the other.

Comment: Also, `range(4)` goes from 0 to 3, not 1 to 4.

Comment: Bitwise operators operate on binary data. It's common to write the argument in hex because each digit corresponds to 4 bits in binary. This makes it easier to tell what the binary value will be.

Comment: The `while n < 10000:` loop can be more simply be written as `for _ in range(10000):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code uses nested loops, so it's processing the cartesian product of 0 through 3. Unrolled, it's equivalent to

```
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>0 & (0x08>>0))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>0 & (0x08>>1))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>0 & (0x08>>2))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>0 & (0x08>>3))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>1 & (0x08>>0))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>1 & (0x08>>1))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>1 & (0x08>>2))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>1 & (0x08>>3))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>2 & (0x08>>0))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>2 & (0x08>>1))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>2 & (0x08>>2))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>2 & (0x08>>3))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>3 & (0x08>>0))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>3 & (0x08>>1))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>3 & (0x08>>2))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>3 & (0x08>>3))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
```

Your version only performs the steps where `i == j`. It's also going from 1 to 4 instead of 0 to 3.

Comment: this makes more sense with the range func starting at 0 and ending 3. thanks for this clarification. my next question is, what is happening in a break down for 0x99 >> 1 and 08 >> 1. could you explain this to me, the Origional code is alot cleaner granted. i am trying to figure out how they came to this cleaner method and what is happening in this Hex bitwise operation.

Comment: in the origional Code, (not copied here) to rotate the motor, they have it like so:
GPIO.output(motorPin[i],0x99<<j & (0x80>>i))   where the 0x80 is now flipped from 08 from the origional. my brain is trying to understand this

Comment: What don't you understand? `0x99 >> 1` is `0x4c`. `0x08 >> 1` is `0x04`. Then it performs a bitwise AND, the result is `0x04`

Comment: I have no idea what any of these bits represent in the motor driver.

Comment: heres an example, the following link shows the motor and driver, however the code doesnt work (at least for me it didnt, except for the code i provided.) granted the solution you provided worked, and now im just trying to further my education on the case.
in the link provided, you will see a sequence = [1000,0100,0010,0001]. my understanding so far, is the motor requires this bit sequence for it to enable the coil a full rotation. however, the 0x99 >> method was able to do this, much more effectively and actually worked in my case.

Comment: here is the link https://microcontrollerslab.com/28byj-48-stepper-motor-raspberry-pi-pico-micropython/

Comment: I'm not really interested in the microcontroller. You asked why your code doesn't do the same thing as the original code, I answered it.

Comment: fair enough, thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Looks like You don't use 'n' parameter:

in your code:

```
    n = 1
    while n < 10000:

        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>1 & (0x08>>1))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(23,0x99>>2 & (0x08>>2))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(24,0x99>>3 & (0x08>>3))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(25,0x99>>4 & (0x08>>4))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        n+= 1
```

try with follow:

```
    n = 1
    while n < 10000:

        GPIO.output(18,0x99>>n+1 & (0x08>>n+1))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(23,0x99>>n+2 & (0x08>>n+2))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(24,0x99>>n+3 & (0x08>>n+3))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        GPIO.output(25,0x99>>n+4 & (0x08>>n+4))
        sleep(stepSpeed)
        n+= 1
```

Comment: The original code doesn't use `n` that way. It's only used to repeat everything 1000 times.

Comment: Barmar is right, the N was used as a placeholder for the while loop count value.